# Python -find all enclosed areas from line coordinate list

Tags: python, algorithm, coordinates, line

I try to find all enclosed areas in cad drawings.

I imported the coordinates (from dxf file) to tuples [((x1,y1),(x2,y2)),...] and tried to find the loops.
First I use **for** loops to find the next line from a coordinate list.
If the last in the results list - I added this loop to the results.
After that, I used the recursive functions, but the for loop didn't iterate if I had multiple pairs.
In example:

```
def process(self):
        "recursive process"
        global polynrs,polycrs,last    
        
        def nextItems(ids,lines,keys,coords,self):            
            results=[] # list of results
            # iterate coords and keys (IDs)
            for i, coord in enumerate(coords):
                key = keys[i] 
                # if the last coordinate and the current coord is same
                # and the ID of lines are different
                if lines[-1] in coord[:2] and key != ids[-1]:
                    results.append(key)
            [checkLoop(ids,lines,keys,coords,k,self) for k in results]  
        
        def checkLoop(ids,lines,keys,coords,pair):
            global polynrs,polycrs            
            if lines[-1] in lines[:-1]:
                n=lines.index(lines[-1])
                lines = lines[n:-1]
                ids = ids[n:]
                if sorted(ids) not in [sorted(i) for i in polynrs]:         
                    polynrs.append(ids)
                    polycrs.append(lines)
            else:
                if lines[-1] in coords[keys.index(pair)]:
                    c = coords[keys.index(pair)]
                    n=abs(c.index(lines[-1])-1)
                    lines.append(c[n])
                    ids.append(pair)
                    nextItems(ids,lines,keys,coords)

        polynrs =   []  # polygon ID list  
        polycrs =   []  # polygon coordinates list   
        keys    =   [i for i in self.coordinates] # get all IDs from dict
        coords  =   [i[:2] for i in self.coordinates.values()] #get all coordinates from dict    

        for i,key in enumerate(keys):
            coord=coords[i]
            lines    =   [coord[0],coord[1]]
            ids     =   [key]           
            nextItems(ids,lines,keys,coords)
```

Finally, I tried with classes and recursive functions but always found the first pair.
I want to avoid loops that have inner lines like the one in the picture.

What is the best method for this task?

[image]

Comment: Can you provide us with a minimum, self-contained *code* example that explains exactly what you want to achieve? The image is a nice addition, but with your explanation alone I can only guess what you want.

Comment: Yes, I added one of the tried code. The issue is that, if there are more variation, the code goes to first results, after that it find the earlier enclosed area and skipped them.